# IE8 positioned background doesn't show

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background, internet-explorer-8

I am having a bit on an issue with an image background not showing up in IE8. Here is a page http://www.bdo.co.uk/budget/tax-data-guide/corporate-tax and the arrows on the accordion are not showing up.

The css is:

```
.closed h2.accordion_h3    {
    background: url(mysource_files/down.png) no-repeat right 10px bottom 10px;
    min-height:24px;
}

.open h2.accordion_h3    {
    background: url(mysource_files/up.png) no-repeat right 10px bottom 10px;
    min-height:24px;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea why this would be happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey change your code to this:

```
url(http://www.bdo.co.uk/__data/assets/image/0006/176613/down.png?v=0.1.1) 99% 10px no-repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using background-position-x and background-position-y property which is compatible till IE9 only if you want to use it in IE8 then you need to use -ms-background-position-x and  -ms-background-position-y  extension to CSS

useful link http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/properties/background-position-x

Hope it helps!